# Worklight Quality Assurance https setup

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, ssl-certificate, mobilefirst-qa

I recently setup https on a Worklight Quality Assurance virtual appliance. I provided the certificate signed by my CA following the directions on the IBM Knowledge Center:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.install.doc/topics/t_confighttps.html?lang=en

and configured the appliance to accept connection only in https (I disabled port 80 through the firewall configuration wizard).

However, when I try to connect on https, the certificate retrieved by the browser is the default certificate issued by the appliance.

Is this correct? I was expecting the browser to retrieve the certificate I just imported.

Many thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if the certificate has been updated properly is to check the modified date of the cert and the key.